# Python while true loop nested if statement indentation

Tags: python

I am terrible with python's indented syntax and I am trying to get this while loop working. What I am looking for is after `hourly()` runs it will ask to export than if `y` it will export then ask if you would like to get the weather for another city. If they choose yes continue and run `hourly()`.

As of right now when you answer yes or no to the first question it going to the beginning of the loop and restarts `hourly()`.

Can someone help me identify my problem here?

```
while True:
    hourly()
    while True:
        export = raw_input('Would you like to export to csv? (y/n): ')
        if export in ('y', 'n'):
            break
            print 'Invalid input.'
        if export == 'y':
            csv_writer(data, path)
            print("Forcast export sucessful")            
        else:
            answer = raw_input('Would you like to get weather for another city? (y/n): ')
            if answer in ('y', 'n'):
                break
                print 'Invalid input.'
            if answer == 'y':
                continue
            else:
                print 'Goodbye'
                break
```

Comment: I am not sure why 'y' and 'n' are invalid inputs.

Comment: A `break` right before a `print` will also cause the print not to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by writing the code you want without any loops: execute `hourly` once, then export to a CSV file (or not):

```
hourly()
export = raw_input('Export to csv? (y/n): ')
if export == 'y':
    csv_writer(data, path)
    print("Forecast export successful")
```

In each of the following, we'll add a bit of functionality one step at a time. Each addition to the previous block of code will be marked with `# new`.

Now let's add the first loop. What if the user doesn't enter "y" or "n" in response to the question? Then we want to repeat that call to `raw_input`, and *nothing* else:

```
hourly()
while True:                                                          # new
    export = raw_input('Export to csv? (y/n): ')
    if export in ('y', 'n'):                                         # new
        break                                                        # new
if export == 'y':
    csv_writer(data, path)
    print("Forecast export successful")
```

Next, let's add a loop so that you can run `hourly` forever.

```
while True:                                         # new
    hourly()
    while True:
        export = raw_input('Export to csv? (y/n): ')
        if export in ('y', 'n'):
            break
    if export == 'y':
        csv_writer(data, path)
        print("Forecast export successful")
```

Forever is a long time; let's give the user the option to quit each time through the outer loop:

```
while True:
    hourly()
    while True:
        export = raw_input('Export to csv? (y/n): ')
        if export in ('y', 'n'):
            break
    if export == 'y':
        csv_writer(data, path)
        print("Forecast export successful")
    answer = raw_input('Another city? (y/n): ')      # new
    if answer == 'n':                                # new
        break                                        # new
```

Note that we don't have to explicitly continue on a `y` answer right now; we could assume that any answer other than `n` means to repeat, so we can simply return to the top of the loop by doing nothing. But let's say you want to enforce a y/n answer. Then we add another loop just as we did before when we asked about exporting the result.

```
while True:
    hourly()
    while True:
        export = raw_input('Export to csv? (y/n): ')
        if export in ('y', 'n'):
            break
    if export == 'y':
        csv_writer(data, path)
        print("Forecast export successful")
    while True:                                         # new
        answer = raw_input('Another city? (y/n): ')
        if answer in ('y', 'n'):                        # new
            break                                       # new
    if answer == 'n':
        break
```

Now, any answer other than `y` or `n` will ask about getting weather again. Once we break out of that inner loop, we check the value of `answer`; if it is `n`, we break the outer loop, otherwise (meaning `answer == 'y'`), we implicitly go back to the top of the outer loop.

---

One final note: you may notice some similarities in the code to get an answer. We can refactor that into a function that guarantees a Y/N answer.

```
def get_yes_no(prompt):
    while True:
        response = raw_input(prompt)
        if response in ('y', 'n'):
            return response
```

Here, the `return` statement takes the place of the `break` statement; returning from the function implicitly breaks out of the loop. Our function can then be used twice in our code:

```
while True:
    hourly()
    export = get_yes_no('Export to csv ? (y/n): ')
    if export == 'y':
        csv_writer(data, path)
        print("Forecast export successful")
    answer = get_yes_no('Another city? (y/n): ')
    if answer == 'n':
        break
```

Comment: Wow this is a great answer and really helped me understand how to nest while loop in python and also solved my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> when you answer yes or no to the first question it going to the beginning of the loop and restarts `hourly()`

That's because you `break` the second `while True` when you answer yes or no...

```
while True:
    hourly()
    while True:
        export = raw_input('Would you like to export to csv? (y/n): ')
        if export in ('y', 'n'):
            break # <--- The problem
```

Perhaps you meant

```
if export not in ('y', 'n'):
```

Same for

```
if answer not in ('y', 'n'):
```