# Print in a while loop

Tags: python, format

I can get the `print` statements to display to terminal if I enter a number that is not equivalent to 15. I want to display a message when the input is not 15, but it won't. Only when I enter 15, I get only "Right Guess". Why does this not work?

```
x=15
y=10

while x != y:

        y = int(input("Please Try to guess the random number: "))
if y < x:
       print("Low guess")
elif y > x:
    print("High Guess")
else :
    print ("Right Guess!")
```

Comment: Indent your code properly!

Comment: Watch your spacing and enjoy the homework.

Comment: In response to your comment on the answer, it is _not_ working. The only way your `while x != y:` loop can break is if you enter `15` as an input. Only _then_ is it possible to do the `if y < x:` etc. checks. Until that point, you just repeatedly ask for `y = int(input("Please Try to guess the random number: "))`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python while true loop nested if statement indentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37666104/python-while-true-loop-nested-if-statement-indentation)

Answer (score 1):

Your `if`, `elif`, and `else` is not in the while loop. This means it won't run until after the while loop is finished (when `x == y`)

You should also use descriptive variable names (not `x` and `y`)

I'm on my phone, so I can't test code, but I think working code would be:

```
number = 15
# why did you initialize your `y` to 10?
guess = 0

while guess != number:
    guess = int(input("Guess a number:")) 
    if guess == number:
        print("Yay! You guessed the number")
    elif guess > number:
        print("You guessed too high")
    else:
        print("You guessed too low")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should indent your code properly.
Initialize your values, these have to be separated from the while loop, otherwise you will get an infinite loop.

```
x = 15
y = 10
```

Then you can run your script below with properly identation.

```py
while x != y:
    y = int(input("Please Try to guess the random number: "))
    if y < x:
        print("Low guess")
    elif y > x:
        print("High Guess")
    else:
        print ("Right Guess!")
```

---

## Identation

**Identation** for python means tell us when a function start and when finish:

```py
if x != y:
    # start indent
    print("I'm in if")
    # finish indent
print("I'm out of if")
```

There, indent tell us when **if** starts and when finishes. So the first print will be affected by **if** and the other print not.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to indent your if block so that it is contained within the while loop.

Comment: I think it's working, it keeps asking for a new value for Y if the previous one does not equal 15